# How to access elements of matrices from mat file in python?

Tags: python, matlab

When load matrices from mat file in python using `scipy.io`, it makes dictionary where key is name of matrix,and value is 2D array of that matrix.

How can i access elements in this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
mat = sio.loadmat('a.mat')
```

Then you can see which matrices were loaded by

```
print mat
```

For each key `key` in the dictionary, you can retrieve the corresponding matrix by

```
my_matrix = mat[key]
```

`my_matrix` is a 2d array representing the matrix.  So to get row 0 of the matrix, you would use `my_matrix[0]`, and to get element(0,0) of the matrix, you would use `my_matrix[0][0]`.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) you can use for other basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
matrix[x][y]
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = array([ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> A[0]
array([1, 2])
>>> A[0][0]
1
```

Here A can be a value in the dict object you have created.